# how to pass # in anchor function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to use the anchor function in ci. My code is

```
<?php 
echo anchor("#",'Delete',['class'=>'btn btn-danger','onclick'=>"delData({$value->id})"]);
?>
```

It's taking base URL and then hash in href but I just need #

Comment: `anchor` have first `param` which will append to your `site_url` you cannot do this with `anchor` function. do it with the manual way

Comment: just write it out...

Comment: If you want something for the user to click on so that some JavaScript runs then **use a `<button type="button">`**. Don't use a link to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Do it without using `anchor` and use HTML markup instead.

```
<a href="#" class='btn btn-danger' onclick='delData(<?= $value->id; ?>)'>Delete</a>
```